# Дать название списку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пользователь вводит название, допустим "test", это название становится переменной списка, т.е. мне надо получить нечто похожее по смыслу

```
input() = []
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: используйте словарь: `dct = {input(): [...]}`

Comment: DeMeNToR для каких целей вам нужно это?

Comment: @Александр создание конвентора для сохранения некоторых данных из элемента gui-шки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

странная хотелка

первое решение (может не совсем то, что вы хотите):

```
list_name = input('введите имя списка: ')
globals()[list_name] = []

xxx.append(12)
print(xxx)
```

код будет работать и выведет `[12]` если пользователь введет `xxx`

второе решение

```
list_name = input('введите имя списка: ')

data = dict()
data[list_name] = [1, 2, 3]

list_name2 = input('введите имя списка из которого получить данные: ')
print(data[list_name])
```

если ввести `xxx`, то будет создан список, которому будет соответствовать запись 'xxx' в словаре

если ввести `xxx` во время второго запроса, то будет выведено `[1, 2, 3]` из словаря

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вроде задача простая, но мозги уже плавятся)